# how to make other items of RecyclerView wait for an animation that is being processed

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

[image]
[image]

So guys I am animating my `recyclerView` items, if you see there is **show Details OR Hide Details** when clicked each they animate.

My problem is when they animate the other `items` acts instantly before animation is done, when I click hide details the other `items` instantly move under the adapter while it is still on animation.